# Apple iPad and PDF support

Tags: ipad, pdf, quartz-2d

I have few questions related to the PDF and its use on the Apple iPad:

1) Does the iPad support all Quartz PDF functions (i.e. all CGPDFxxx functions/classes)?

2) Does the iPad support the PDF Kit?

3) Is it possible with any of one of both APIs, based on the coordinates of the finger touch to detect the underlying PDF item (e.g. article, text, annotations) ?

4) What is the difference between the Quartz PDF functions and PDF Kit?

Thanks a lot
Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 4):

1) Yes, at least, I haven't come across any unsupported functions.

2) No.

3) Not natively but you may be able to inspect the PDF (in the docs somewhere) and determine position/size/type of various elements and create an overlay or use hitTest.

4) PDF Kit includes an PDF specific UIView subclass (usable in IB) and tons of methods for easily interacting with the content of the PDF including images, text selection, annotation, etc. Essentially it's just a bunch of features built on top of Quartz for your convenience.